# How to read output of a command in Git Bash through Autohotkey

Tags: git, autohotkey

I am trying to send a command to Git Bash terminal through Autohotkey but unable to find a way to read its output. Is there a simple way for it? I am sending this

Run, C:\Users\Unknown\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe
sleep, 2000

Send cd /c/Users/Unknown/Desktop/git/fw{Enter}

sleep, 1000

Send  git log --pretty=format:'`%h' -n 1{Enter}

The answer to this is a commit number displayed on terminal

How can I read it?

Thanks

Comment: Try [WinGetText](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetText.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Capturing Output

To capture the output from a command, you can use one of the following `RunWaitOne()` functions.

**Option 1:** Doesn't use a temporary file and can't hide the command window. ([Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#Examples))

```
; From https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#Examples
RunWaitOne(command) {
  shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
  exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C """ command """") ; change: added '"' around command
  return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}
```

**Option 2:** Uses a temporary file and the command window is hidden. (Released under [WTFPL](https://wtfpl.net))

```
RunWaitOne(command) {
  tmpFile := A_Temp . "\" . A_ScriptName . "_RunWaitOne.tmp"
  RunWait, % ComSpec . " /c """ . command . " > """ . tmpFile . """""",, Hide
  FileRead, result, %tmpFile%
  FileDelete, %tmpFile%
  return result
}
```

## Working Example

I personally don't like hard coding in paths, so the following answer is set up to do the following steps:

1. Look for a Git install on the system PATH environment variable and store it as `GIT_BIN_DIR`
2. If an install hasn't been found yet, look for one in the default install directories and store it as `GIT_BIN_DIR`
3. Show an error message if Git couldn't be found and quit.
4. Queue the commands to be called.
5. Execute the commands and store the result in variable `result`.
6. Display the result

#### The Code

Code is released under [WTFPL](https://wtfpl.net)

```
; STEP 1: Try to find Git on PATH
EnvGet, E_PATH, PATH
GIT_BIN_DIR := ""
for i, path in StrSplit(E_PATH, ";")
{
  if (RegExMatch(path, "i)Git\\cmd$")) {
    SplitPath, path, , parent
    GIT_BIN_DIR := parent . "\bin"
    break
  }
}

; STEP 2: Fallback to default install directories.
if (GIT_BIN_DIR == "") {
  allUsersPath := A_ProgramFiles . "\Git\bin"
  currentUserPath := A_AppData . "\Programs\Git\bin"
  if (InStr(FileExist(currentUserPath), "D"))
    GIT_BIN_DIR := currentUserPath
  else if (InStr(FileExist(allUsersPath), "D"))
    GIT_BIN_DIR := allUsersPath
}

; STEP 3: Show error Git couldn't be found.
if (GIT_BIN_DIR == "") {
  MsgBox 0x1010,, Could not find Git's 'bin' directory
  ExitApp
}

; STEP 4 - Queue any commands.
; commands becomes "line1 & line2 & ..." thanks to the Join continuation section
commands := "
(Join`s&`s
cd /c/Users/Unknown/Desktop/git/fw
git log --pretty=format:'`%h' -n 1
)"

; STEP 5 - Execute the commands (Uses "Git\bin\sh.exe" so we can capture output)
result := RunWaitOne("""" . GIT_BIN_DIR . "\sh.exe"" --login -i -c """ . commands . """")

; STEP 6 - Show the result
MsgBox 0x1040,, % result
```